# Example of how to use node-wordpress

Tags: wordpress, node.js

I am trying to run wordpress RPC methods with [node-wordpress](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress) library but as there is no documentation at all, I am not sure what's the proper way to run it.

Could you please show some examples if you had a chance to work with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to get it done by reading the module itself.

First you start the client:

```
var wp = wordpress.createClient({
            "url": 'http://yourwordpressURL', 
            "username": 'user', 
            "password": 'pwd' 
});
```

than to add a post, for instance, just make the following call:

```
wp.newPost({
      title: 'Your title',
      status: 'publish', //'publish, draft...',
      content: '<strong>This is the content</strong>',
      author: 3, // author id
      terms: {'category': [category_id]}
    },
    function() { 
      console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

All the documentation for wordpress is in http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts

Hope that helps.

Comment: This saved me about 3 hours of troubling shooting. Cheers!